# Google Sheets API Post

Tags: node.js, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm working on a **chatbot project**. I want users to be able to enter list items onto a Google Sheet. The chatbot is on DialogFlow, I created the intent, and toggled the webhook on. I am now in Google Cloud Functions and creating a function to **POST** the new item on the google sheet. I have already been **successfully able to read (GET)** the list of items from the sheet to be displayed to the user in the chatbot.

I am new to nodejs and admittedly don't know much about Oauth, but I set my sheet to be able to be edited by anyone on the internet and I have a working API key as well. To try to just get down to basics, I went on https://apitester.com to test the HTTP request there. **I can GET a response easily that returns the list of items I already have. However, my POST response is still returning issues, although the site did indicate that the request "PASS"ed.**

My POST request

```
https://sheets.google.com/v4/spreadsheet/<SPREADSHEETID>/values/A1:append?includeValuesInResponse=true&key=<MY_API_KEY>
```

where `<SPREADSHEETID>` and `<MY_API_KEY>` match my credentials.

My request body:

```
{
  "values": [ ["Hello", "World"] ],
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:B1",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS"
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets?usp=direct_url
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 07:31:14 GMT
Expires: Sat, 17 Nov 2018 07:31:14 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: sffe
Content-Length: 248
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
```

I looked up the **301 error code** and found that it is a redirection message that signifies a server-side error. I read that it should be self-fixing as your request will just be-redirected to the appropriate site in the `Location` value above. But I also copied the `Location` link and found it just took me to my personal Google Drive. I read elsewhere that this may occur because Google is communicating over a secure link. I checked my Google sheet just in case, *but nothing had changed there*.

**Anyway, is it possible to test the append request before I code it into my Google Cloud Function? If so, where can I test and how can I make sure that the request goes through (with hopefully just an API key and no Oauth creds)?**

I tried doing this on the documentation page (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) ("Try This API" on the right-hand side) but I just get a never-ending red progress circle.

Please help! If the only answer is Oauth, please help me past directing me to the Oauth documentation, as I have not found that very helpful.

***Thank you!***

**EDIT 1**
Okay, I have been trying some things out. Oauth playground wasn't working for me, but this website (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.values.append) allowed me to POST a new row to my spreadsheet. (I had to toggle Authorize OAuth 2.0 to ON.)

So now I have the Oauth working, how can I translate this into my Google Cloud Function using node.js? Do I save my Oauth tokens to certain variables and then add them to headers?

Comment: Where did you read that a 301 is a server-side error? HTTP 301 means "Moved Permanently", indicating you should be using the "Location" URL in the future. However, `https://sheets.google.com` is not an API, you probably meant `https://sheets.googleapis.com`, which probably explains the unexpected response. Can you update your post after correcting that URL in your process?